# 7 million+ records that i need to apply multiple formula to it

Tags: c#, sql

I have 7 million+ records that i need to apply multiple formula to it.
This is how i am doing it:
I am converting my formula to shunting Yard Algorithm then using "find and replace" the variable then using Reverse Polish notation to convert to a double ... 
for instance:
 y= ( 3 + X + RMT + T ) + 5 
replace X by 6
replace RMT by 5.9
replace T by whatever...

it is taking too long.
Can i speed it up ?
thank's

Note: the formula are dynamic and can change...

Comment: Can you share code and _any_ stats you have regarding performance?

Comment: I'm envisioning different scenario's, please clarify. First possibility: You have several formula's (F,G,H,...) and you want to apply F to each record, then G to each record, etc, but that once F,G,H have been defined they do not change (G could depend on the result of F and etc).  Second possibility: the formula F changes based on previously calculated values and there is some sequential order the records must be calculated.  Third possibility: the formula changes, but not dependent on the values it calculated, perhaps from an outside party.  Please clarify the cause of the formula changing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it is taking too long

Use a profiler, fix your application.

I have a problem seeing a simple formula like that on a properly multi core system with parallelizaton taking more than a tenth off a second to do 7 million updates when a properly programmed interpreter is attached there.

Perfomrance for something like that is an implementation detail, and you lack ANY information.

NOrmally the usual applies - it is too slow, pull up a profiler and FIND OUT WHY.